# If all bits of an IP are 0, the address refers to this host on this network. What exactly "this" means?

Tags: ip, ping

I was studying about the IP Class and reserved IP.
Somewhere it said "If an IP address consists of all zeros, the address refers to this host on this network." 
What is referred to "this" in phrase "this host on this network"

Comment: The host that your code is running on.

Comment: Where did you read that? It isn't correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally, the IPv4 address of all `0` (`0.0.0.0`) meant "This Network." That referred to the fact that it was used as a broadcast address for the network. It is, for all practical purposes, an invalid host address. It is often used for things like routing protocols with a mask length of `0` (`0.0.0/0`) to represent any address (default route).

The address of all `1` (`255.255.255.255`) is known as the "Limited Broadcast" address.

The original IP RFCs created the network classes, but they have since been obsoleted by RFCs creating Classless Interdomain Routing (CIDR) and Variable Length Subnet Masking (VLSM). I'm not sure why classful network is still taught today since it isn't really used anymore, but:

- Class A addresses all start with a `0` as the first bit in the
  address (`0.0.0.0` to `127.255.255.255`), and they have an 8-bit mask
  (`255.0.0.0`).
- Class B addresses all start with `10` as the first two bits in the
  address (`128.0.0.0` to `191.255.255.255`), and they have a 16-bit
  mask (`255.255.0.0`).
- Class C addresses all start with `110` as the first three bits in the
  address (`192.0.0.0` to `223.255.255.255`), and they have a 24-bit
  mask (`255.255.255.0`).
- Class D addresses (today, used for multicast) all start with `1110`
  as the first four bits of the address (`224.0.0.0` to
  `239.255.255.255`). Multicast doesn't use address masks since each
  multicast address represents a multicast group to which host listen
  to individually.
- Class E addresses (reserved or experimental) all start with `1111` as
  the first four bits of the address (`240.0.0.0` to
  `255.255.255.255`). Since these are all (except the Limited Broadcast
  address) are invalid addresses, they do not use masks.

CIDR and VLSM did away with classful networking, and you should now look at a practical valid address as a series of bits in the range of `1.0.0.0` to `223.255.255.255`, having a practical mask length of between `8` (`255.0.0.0`) and `32` (`255.255.255.255`).

In reality, IPv4 addresses and masks are just 32-bit unsigned integers on which to perform logical operations. When you are given problems involving IP addresses and masks, it is far easier to convert the dotted-decimal notation into binary to perform the operations, and then convert back to dotted-decimal for the final answer.

Comment: Nice Explanation! BTW, why they still teach Classful networks? Coz thats the base of how networks and how they were originally setup. Someone learning about networks for the first time wouldn't understand VLSM and CIDR unless they understand classful subnets. These were created to overcome the limitations of classful subnets. Classful subnets are still being used for private networks and will continue  as the limitations dont apply to private networks.

Comment: @LuckyChingi, I think it is easier to learn IP addressing by, what is essentially CIDR and VLSM, just doing binary bit manipulation. Classes simply put constraints on this. Once someone learns how to do the bit manipulation without worrying about classes, then classes could be introduced, if necessary. Routing protocols are now classless. Private networks don't really use classes; they often subnet by octet boundary and call that classes. When using the Class A private network, I have server guys insist they need a Class C, and they incorrectly insist that is determined by the mask.

Answer (score 1):

What `0.0.0.0` means depends on the context.

To a server process, it means "all IP addresses configured on this host." Let's say you have a host with multiple IP addresses configured, and you want to run a web server on port 443. You can either tell the web server to bind to a specific IP address, or you can tell it to bind to `0.0.0.0`,  meaning "bind to all IP addresses configured on this host."

In the context of a routing table, it means "the default route," which is sometimes expressed as `0.0.0.0/0`. An example routing table:

```
$ netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.131.64.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.131.64.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.192.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
```

This table shows that `0.0.0.0` (the default route) points to the gateway `10.131.64.1`. It then points other destinations to the default route at `0.0.0.0`.

Here is an iptables ruleset snippet showing the CIDR notation `0.0.0.0/0`. You can think of these entries being "FROM any TO any."

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

It is also used in some other cases, e.g. when a host comes up on a network and asks for address assignment via DHCP. If the host has no prior assigned address to try to use, it will be `0.0.0.0` until it has something assigned.

This is all in IPv4. In IPv6, you would see `::/0` instead.

Answer (score -1):

A network is a created by using the subnets, mainly class A,B and C

now IPV4 has 4 octets with 8 bits each

11111111.11111111.11111111.11111111

Now if I take an IP whose bits are as under
11111111.11111111.11111111.11111110
 and the subnet is 
11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000

It is an ip on the network of a particular subnet, in this example Class C

The 'this network' implies the IP addresses is a member of the network like 
11111111.11111111.11111111.11111000
or

11111111.11111111.11111111.11111100

Comment: You are under some misconceptions about network classes. First, classful routing is dead, preempted many years ago by the VLSM RFCs. Second, The old classful network class is defined by the first few bits of an address: Class A addresses start with a `0` bit, Class B addresses start with `10`, Class C addresses start with `110`, Class D addresses start with `1110` and Class E addresses start with `1111`. This is all detailed in to original RFC. It meas that your address example of a Class C address falls under the old Class E, which is actually an invalid address.

Comment: Thanks @RonMaupin, please explain to the person who created this question. I tried to explain in a simpler way - your turn now :)